# breaking up long path names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble breaking the path into two lines in my python compiler.
It is simply a long path on the compiler screen and i have to stretch the window too wide. I know how to break a print("string") into two lines of code that will compile correctly, but not an open(path). As I write this I notice the text box can not even hold it all on one line. 
print()

```
`raw_StringFile = open(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\year 2013\testfiles\test          code\rawstringfiles.txt', 'a')`
```

Comment: Very helpful tips for long path names here. I think the r prefix being used on multiple lines helped a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is what the `\` is for.

```
>>> mystr = "long" \
... "str"
>>> mystr
'longstr'
```

Or in your case:

```
longStr = r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\year 2013\testfiles" \
           r"\testcode\rawstringfiles.txt"
raw_StringFile = open(longStr, 'a')
```

**EDIT**

Well, you don't even need the `\` if you use parenthesis, i.e.:

```
longStr = (r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\year 2013\testfiles"
               r"\testcode\rawstringfiles.txt")
raw_StringFile = open(longStr, 'a')
```

Comment: Using \ at the end of lines isn't PEP8ish

Answer (score 7):

Python permits concatenating strings merely by placing them adjacently:

```
In [67]: 'abc''def'
Out[67]: 'abcdef'

In [68]: r'abc'r'def'
Out[68]: 'abcdef'

In [69]: (r'abc'
   ....: r'def')
Out[69]: 'abcdef'
```

So something like this ought to work for you.

```
raw_StringFile = open(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\year 2013\testfiles'
                      r'\testcode\rawstringfiles.txt', 'a')
```

Another option is to use `os.path.join`:

```
myPath = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\year 2013\testfiles',
                      r'testcode\rawstringfiles.txt')
raw_StringFile = open(myPath, 'a')
```

Comment: You cannot use a backslash as the last character in a raw string literal.

Answer (score 3):

You can place your string inside parenthesis, like this:

```
>>> (r'C:\Users\Public\Documents'
...  r'\year 2013\testfiles\test          code'
...  r'\rawstringfiles.txt')
'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\year 2013\\testfiles\\test          code\\rawstringfiles.txt'
```

This is called "String literal concatenation". Quote from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly
>   using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is
>   the same as their concatenation. Thus, "hello" 'world' is equivalent
>   to "helloworld". This feature can be used to reduce the number of
>   backslashes needed, to split long strings conveniently across long
>   lines, or even to add comments to parts of strings, for example:
>
> ```
> re.compile("[A-Za-z_]"       # letter or underscore
>            "[A-Za-z0-9_]*"   # letter, digit or underscore
> )
> ```

Also see:

- [Python style - line continuation with strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437619/python-style-line-continuation-with-strings)
- [Quoting long strings without newlines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076979/quoting-long-strings-without-newlines-in-python)
- [How to declare a long string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577027/long-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Python has a nifty feature called [Implicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining).

> Expressions in parentheses, square brackets or curly braces can be split over more than one physical line without using backslashes. For example:

```
month_names = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Maart',      # These are the
               'April',   'Mei',      'Juni',       # Dutch names
               'Juli',    'Augustus', 'September',  # for the months
               'Oktober', 'November', 'December']   # of the year
```

So for your question -

```
raw_StringFile = open(r'C:\Users\Public\Documents\year 2013\testfiles'
                      r'\testcode\rawstringfiles.txt', 'a')
```

**EDIT** - In this example, it is actually [String literal concatenation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).